# Maven: Error resolving version for plugin

Tags: maven, netbeans

I am trying to get Batik working, having not worked with Java much in the last ten years or so and I'm running into problems with Maven being able to find the `org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ssh-external` package.

When I open or try to build the project in Netbeans, it reports the following error:

```
   The project org.freehep:freehep-graphicsio:2.1.1 (/home/glenatron/Projects/batik/freehep-graphicsio/pom.xml) has 1 error
     Unresolveable build extension: 
     Error resolving version for plugin 'org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ssh-external' from the repositories [local (/home/glenatron/.m2/repository), freehep-maven (http://java.freehep.org/maven2), central (http://www.ibiblio.org/maven2), Codehaus (http://repository.codehaus.org/), Codehaus Snapshots (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/)]:
     Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 2]
```

As far as I can tell this is correct, however, I have the following in my `pom.xml` file for the project:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>freehep-maven</id>
      <name>Maven FreeHEP</name>
      <url>http://java.freehep.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-apache</id>
        <name>Maven Apache</name>
        <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>    
        <id>maven1</id>
        <name>Maven.org</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

From what I can judge a) that plugin should be available in one of those repositories and b) if they are in the `pom.xml` file, Maven should be searching them but I can't see any sign of it doing that.

The project I am trying to work with is [the FreeHEP EMF driver.](http://java.freehep.org/vectorgraphics/freehep-graphicsio-emf/source-repository.html) The bigger screen solution was to use the unsignposted but much more up to date [Github repository](http://freehep.github.io/freehep-vectorgraphics/index.html) version.

Comment: Remove the entries with `repo1...` cause this is maven Central and used by Maven by default so no need to define it explicit. Furthermore the given [`freehep.org`](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|freehep-graphicsio) is also available via Maven Central. So if i see it correct you don't need to define supplemental repositories at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the solution was in the message after all: Error resolving version for **plugin.**

So obviously it's not a `repository` it is a `pluginRepository` which goes in a different part of `pom.xml`:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>    
        <id>maven1</id>
        <name>Maven.org</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Which does not help, cause this is defined in maven by default so no need to give it explicitly.

Comment: @khmarbaise depends what you mean by "help" - with that addition I can build the project, without it I can't. Possibly Netbeans is doing something wack to Maven and hiding it's standard configuration somehow? Either way, this solved the problem for me.

Comment: If you need such configuration you already changed the default configuration. Is there any settings.xml file in your user home folder?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the entries with `repo1...` cause this is maven Central and used by Maven by default so no need to define it explicit. Furthermore the given [`freehep.org`](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|freehep-graphicsio) is also available via Maven Central. So if i see it correct you don't need to define supplemental repositories at all.

Comment: Will having them in the `pom` file prevent it from querying them? That seems a slightly esoteric behaviour.

Comment: you don't need them...so don't configure them. Apart from that that the freehep.org is an old repository which seemed to be out of date. Are you behind a proxy? Can you show the project you are trying with somewhere (github) so we can take a better look there.